# Limit access to google app engine endpoint method

Tags: android, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, google-cloud-endpoints

I have a question about the security of Google App Engine endpoints. I have a data inside datastore which I uploaded and that data should be only read from Android app.

I retrieve all the data like this:

```
Personendpoint.Builder endpointBuilder = new Personendpoint.Builder(
                AndroidHttp.newCompatibleTransport(), new JacksonFactory(), null);
        endpointBuilder = CloudEndpointUtils.updateBuilder(endpointBuilder);
        CollectionResponsePerson result;

        Personendpoint endpoint = endpointBuilder.build();


        try {
            result = endpoint.listPerson().execute();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
            result = null;
        }
```

Inside my PersonEndpoint I have this:

```
@Api(name = "personendpoint", namespace = @ApiNamespace(ownerDomain = "test.com", ownerName = "test.com", packagePath = "personmanagement"))
public class PersonEndpoint {

    /**
     * This method lists all the entities inserted in datastore.
     * It uses HTTP GET method and paging support.
     *
     * @return A CollectionResponse class containing the list of all entities
     * persisted and a cursor to the next page.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings({ "unchecked", "unused" })
    @ApiMethod(name = "listPerson")
    public CollectionResponse<Person> listPerson(@Nullable @Named("cursor") String cursorString,
            @Nullable @Named("limit") Integer limit) 
    {
     ...
    }
```

Similar to this there are also methods `insertPerson`, `removePerson` which are dangerous in this case. Attacker can easily trigger those methods and delete data from my datastore. How can it be protected?

I want to allow user only to get the data from the datastore. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you secure your endpoints [with authentication using OAuth](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/endpoints/auth). Besides that, is your responsibility to check roles and permissions of the authenticated user and filter the data he will be managing as any other web app.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily enforce security constraints in your web.xml.

```
<security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>personmanagement</web-resource-name>
        <url-pattern>/personmanagement/*</url-pattern>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <auth-constraint>
        <role-name>*</role-name>
    </auth-constraint>
</security-constraint>
```

This will force users to be authenticated with their Google account to access the URL : `<role-name>*</role-name>`. You can use `<role-name>admin</role-name>` if you want only app administrators to be  able to access the URL (you can add administrators in the cloud console).

See the docs : https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/config/webxml?hl=fr#Security_and_Authentication